# Reorder all items in wordpress feed with start and end date

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss, feed

I'm trying to reorder the default "yourdomainname.com/feed" items in WordPress to be sorted after an start and end date meta value.

I have some code that works perfect in the templates and does the front end. However when I insert pretty much the same code in the `functions.php` file the feed remains "untouched" by it.

Can anyone may be spot or point me in the right direction to what i'm doing wrong? Here is the code that I put in the `functions.php` file.

```
/*
    Sort all posts to be ordered by meta start date.
*/

function feed_filter($query){
    if($query->is_feed){

        // Find todays date
        $date = date('Ymd');

        $query_args = array(
            'meta_query'    => array(
                array(
                    'key'       => 'end_date',
                    'compare'   => '>=',
                    'value'     => $date,
                )
            ),
            'meta_key'          => 'start_date',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'             => 'ASC'
        );

        debugIt($query_args);

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $query_args );

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'feed_filter');
```

Comment: I've updated the code above to close resemble what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by creating my own RSS feed template. Here is an example.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Event RSS layout */ header("Content-type: text/xml"); echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'; ?>

<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>

        <?php

            $date = date('Ymd');

            $args = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'end_date',
                        'compare'   => '>=',
                        'value'     => $date,
                    )
                ),
                'meta_key'          => 'start_date',
                'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                'order'             => 'ASC'
            );

            $posts = get_posts($args);

            foreach ($posts as $post){ setup_postdata($post);

                $date = get_field('start_date'); 
                $date = strftime("%A den %e. %B", strtotime($date));

        ?>

        <item>
            <title><?php echo $date; ?> - <?php the_title(); ?></title>
            <link><?php the_permalink(); ?></link>
            <guid><?php the_permalink(); ?></guid>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>" /><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 40, '...' ); ?>]]>
            </description>
            <pubDate><?php echo date('r', strtotime(get_the_date())); ?></pubDate>
        </item>

        <?php } ?>

    </channel>
</rss>
```